# Checking if Squeeze Theorem is rigorous enough to complete proof of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n = \sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, solution-verification

For reference I am in Introduction to Abstract Math, and have take Calculus 1, Discrete Math, and Linear Algebra.

I am almost completed with my proof, wanted to check if using Squeeze Theorem would be rigorous enough to complete it, or if I made any other logical mistakes in the process.

$a_n,b_n,$ and $m_n$ are defined in:
[Prove that the elements of sequences $(a_n),(b_n)$ are rational numbers such that $a_n<\sqrt{2}<b_n=a_n+2^{-n}$ for all $n \geq 1$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832835/prove-that-the-elements-of-sequences-a-n-b-n-are-rational-numbers-such-tha)

and related information is also in:
[Formal proof of the convergence of the sequence ($2^{-n}$) using definition of convergence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835262/formal-proof-of-the-convergence-of-the-sequence-2-n-using-definition-of-c)

Here's the proof:

Use the definition of convergence to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n = \sqrt{2}$.

Lemma:

Prove that $\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges to $0.$

Claim $2^n > n$ for all integers $n>0$. The base case $2>1$ holds, and if $2^n > n$, then $2^{n+1} = 2 \times 2^n = 2^n + 2^n >n+n>n+1$. This shows that $\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{1}{n}$ by induction for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Now let $\epsilon > 0$. By the Positive Archimedean Property of Real Numbers, positive integers $N$ can be selected such that $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. By solving for $\epsilon$, we get $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. Therefore, for any $n \geq N$, we get
$$|2^{-n}|=\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$$
Therefore, $\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges to 0 by the definition of convergence.

With the lemma, we can now prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$.

Consider that $b_n = a_n + 2^{-n}$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+2^{-n})$. This can be rewritten as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^{-n}$. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^{-n}=0$ by the previous lemma, therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Now, consider $m_n$. By definition, $m_n = \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$. Since $b_n = a_n + 2^{-n}$, then $m_n = \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}=\frac{2a_n+2^{-n}}{2}=a_n+2^{-n} \times \frac{1}{2}$. Now consider $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} m_n$. Because $m_n =a_n+2^{-n} \times \frac{1}{2}$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} m_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+2^{-n}\times \frac{1}{2}) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n + \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(2^{-n}\times \frac{1}{2}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n +\frac{1}{2} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(2^{-n}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

And here's where I'd think to use Squeeze Theorem, since $a_n < m_n < b_n$. Would this be rigorous enough, or would I need to use a different method?

Comment: Why would you use the Squeeze Theorem on $a_n < m_n < b_n$? You already proved that $\lim a_n=\lim m_n=\lim b_n$.

Comment: To show that $\lim m_n = \sqrt{2}$, which would mean $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ are also $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on how I'd do that?

Comment: But you have $\lim a_n=\lim b_n$ and $a_n < \sqrt{2} < b_n$. Why you just don't use this

Comment: You would have $\lim a_n \leq \sqrt{2}$ and $\lim a_n=\lim b_n \geq \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it now.

Comment: Wait, since it isn't $\leq$ but <, I get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n < \sqrt{2} < \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$. Sorry, I'm very very tired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113272/discussion-between-pam1499-and-calypso-rivers).