# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=\sqrt{2}$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}b_n=\sqrt{2}$ using formal definition of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

For reference. I am currently taking Introduction to Abstract Math, and have taken Calculus 1, Linear Algebra, and Discrete Math.

I am stuck on this part of a proof, I am trying to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=\sqrt{2}$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}b_n=\sqrt{2}$ using the formal definition of convergence. $(a_n), (b_n),$ and $(m_n)$ are defined as they are in the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832835/prove-that-the-elements-of-sequences-a-n-b-n-are-rational-numbers-such-tha)

I don't know how I would apply the formal definition of convergence, however. I know that I have to prove that $|a_n - \sqrt{2}| < \epsilon$, and that $|b_n - \sqrt{2}| < \epsilon$, and I proved that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$ in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835262/formal-proof-of-the-convergence-of-the-sequence-2-n-using-definition-of-c), and I also know that $b_n=a_n+2^{-n}$, but I don't know where to go from here. How would I get started on this?

Comment: Remember you also know $a_n < \sqrt 2 < b_n$. So $\lvert \sqrt 2 - a_n \rvert < \lvert b_n - a_n \rvert$, for instance...